# fstab group option?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fstab

**Environment**

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Desktop 64-bit

**Problem**

- only members of *group_name* should be allowed to mount,unmount and read,write,execute *drive_name*

**Potential Solution**

1. edit /etc/fstab add line: `/dev/abc /media/drive_name ext4 group 0 2`
2. create group: `sudo groupadd group_name`
3. add users to group: `sudo adduser user1 group_name`
4. mount point owned by group: `sudo chgrp /media/drive_name group_name`

**Question**

1. Is this the correct, secure way of solving the problem?

Thank you :)

Comment: did you tried it?

Comment: better way you can create a sudo user instead of this. if so you can define only which service the particular sudo user can do.

Comment: I think using automount will do most of what you want. Set it to mount /dev/abc on /media/group_name_private/drive_name, where /media/group_name_private is user root, group group_name, and mode 750. automount doesn't offer a way to immediately unmount, though; you just have to have everyone stop using the filesystem for a minute or two (configurable) and automount will then unmount it.

Comment: You got the arguments in the wrong order on line 4: it should be "chgrp _group_name path_", not "chgrp _path group_name_".

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. From `man mount`:

> the user must be member of  the  group  of  the special file.

Note that it says `special file` and not `mount point`.  If you run `ls -l` against your partitions you'll note that the group owner is `disk`.

Therefore, make `user1` a member of the `disk` group and he/she will be able to mount the partition as long as the `group` option is in the partition's `/etc/fstab` line.

Similarly, make `user` a member of the `cdrom` group and he/she will be able to mount the cdrom after you ensure that `group` is in the cdrom's `/etc/fstab` entry.